# generate less variable dependency tree?

Tags: less

In less, you can have variables that depend on variables that depend on variables etc. pp., like

```lesscss
@a: #000;
@b: @a;
@c: lighten(@b, 50);
@d: darken(@c, 25);
```

with the ability to import multiple files it can get quite messy to know which variable depends on which other variables.

**Is there a way** (e.g. a flag to run lessc with or an external program) **to get the dependency tree of a given less variable?**

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The closest you're going to get is manually adding explanatory comments. If you need those comments in the compiled CSS, make sure to use `/* CSS comments */` (`// LESS comments` don't make it into the compiled CSS).

If you're looking at front-end things in a browser inspector, you can use sourcemaps to track down what file a given style came from, and then read the comments in that file.

If you're minifying your compiled CSS, either don't remove comments or generate an extra non-production copy that doesn't remove comments.

Your example is colors, but note that if dealing with numbers you'll sometimes be able to use `calc()` to have source values show up in the final CSS (including in browser inspectors, if that's relevant to what you're doing).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't really need to know the dependency given a CSS file, I'm perfectly fine if just analyzing the less sources (because with nested imports in 80+ files you not always know what depends on what). CSS would be nice, for sure, but not necessary. I really look for "this variable `@foo` in file `foo.less`, what does it depend on in the files `{bar,baz,...}.less`?"

Comment: Answer's still no, sadly. // Made a small edit to my answer, pointing out you can use `// inline comments` if you don't need it to survive in the compiled CSS.